# postfwd not rate limiting sasl users

Tags: postfix, sasl, postfwd

I would like to use [postfwd](http://postfwd.org) version 2 to limit the amount of daily mail sent by my sasl authenticated users.

I installed latest tarball: postfwd-1.35 with latest postfix from Centos 6.4

In my I have only this rule

```
id=RULEZEROSASL
  sasl_username=~/^(\S+)$/
  action=rcpt(sasl_username/500/86400/REJECT only 500 recipients per day for $$sasl_username)
```

which should reject only mail with authenticated users (not mail from trusted mailservers).

My postfwd2 listens on tcp 10045
and in my postfix main.cf I have

```
# Restriction Classes
smtpd_restriction_classes       = postfwdcheck
postfwdcheck                    = check_policy_service inet:127.0.0.1:10045
127.0.0.1:10045_time_limit      = 3600

...

smtpd_recipient_restrictions =
        permit_mynetworks
        permit_sasl_authenticated
        permit_tls_clientcerts
        reject_unauth_destination
        check_recipient_access  hash:/etc/postfix/access
        reject_invalid_helo_hostname
# postfwd con rate limiting
        check_policy_service inet:127.0.0.1:10045
        warn_if_reject reject_non_fqdn_helo_hostname
        warn_if_reject reject_unknown_helo_hostname
        warn_if_reject reject_unknown_client
        reject_non_fqdn_sender
        reject_non_fqdn_recipient
        reject_unknown_sender_domain
        reject_unknown_recipient_domain
        warn_if_reject reject_unverified_sender
        reject_unverified_recipient
        reject_rbl_client zen.spamhaus.org
        permit
```

in /etc/postfix/policy

```
.   postfwdcheck
```

I see no rule matching entries in log
and the command

```
postfwd2 -vv --dumpcache -f /etc/postfwd.cf
```

shows the request number

```
[STATS] postfwd2::policy 1.35: **5** requests since 0 days, 01:05:31 hours
```

increasing only for manual tests done with:

```
 nc 127.0.0.1 10045 <request.sample
```

Any idea why postfwd is not engaged by postfix?

Comment: If a restriction class returns an OK, it terminates there. So it's probably stopping on `permit_mynetworks`, or `permit_sasl_authenticated`.

Comment: I think you might have more luck putting it in `smtpd_relay_restrictions` as the first entry.

Comment: ehm my actual conf is:
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks
       permit_sasl_authenticated
       reject_unauth_destination

shall I add an check_policy_service inet:127.0.0.1:10045 
on top?

Comment: I don't know, if it's not a production system, I'd say yes :) but put it after `permit_mynetworks`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Postfix restriction classes can return three answers, OK, REJECT or DUNNO, usually they have (OK, DUNNO) or (REJECT, DUNNO), because of the way that postfix functions. DENY and OK mean the rest of the checks are ignored, DUNNO means go on to the next check.

So, in your case, `permit_mynetworks` or `permit_sasl_authenticated` are returning OK, so it does not check further under `smtpd_recipient_restrictions`, though you could place it in another restriction class which will then first have to return OK, for the mail to be forwarded.

Comment: I had good luck just  moving  check_policy_service inet:127.0.0.1:10045
over permit_sasl_authenticated in   smtpd_recipient_restriction
....


Now I have this problem , I always get an empty counter:

 postfwd2/policy[6968]: [RULES] rule=0, id=RULEZEROSASL, client=unknown[x.y.z.w], user=myuser@mydomain.com, sender=<xxxxx@yyy.com>, recipient=<www@zzz.com>, helo=<hhhh>, proto=ESMTP, state=RCPT, ignoring empty counter

Comment: Here I'm a little less sure.. it seems like postfwd isn't catching anything with that regex.

Comment: Try using the `sasl_username=` field by itself? Comment out the regex.

Comment: do you have any example of a working regexp to match any non empty sasl user?

Comment: BTW empty regexp : no luck and lotsa ignoring empty counter

Comment: What does the field look like exactly? From the headers...

Comment: I'm guessing you should only try and match the username itself, maybe [a-z]{3,40}.  It's been too long since I've written PCRE with any frequency.

Comment: mmm looks like sasl user gets not into the outgoing emails headers but
in my maillog, postfwd correctly logs the sasl user into the
user=field   if I use the sasl_username=~/^(\S+)$/  regexp
--------------------------------
Apr 26 16:57:34 mailout04 postfwd2/policy[6970]: [RULES] rule=0, id=RULEZEROSASL, client=unknown[x.y.z.w], user=user@domain.com, sender=<user@domain.com>, reci
pient=<xxxx@yyyy.com>, helo=<SERVERXP>, proto=ESMTP, state=RCPT, ignoring empty counter
-------------

Comment: Add this to your main.cf `smtpd_sasl_authenticated_header = yes`

Comment: maybe counters are not really written into a temporary file or something.... the issue is I have not evident error in logs

Comment: Did you add the option to main.cf?

Comment: Ok now I have an Authenticated sender: name@domain.com in my outgoing headers...  I have sasl senders logged as user=xxx in maillogs but always  state=RCPT, ignoring empty counter

Comment: You may want to ask the guys on the postfwd list: http://listi.jpberlin.de/mailman/listinfo/postfwd-users they'll probably be able to get you a result quicker :)

Comment: No problems.. remember to do the same when you can :)

Comment: at the end it did work: I just used in main.cf
--------------------------------------
smtpd_data_restrictions =
        reject_unauth_pipelining,
        reject_multi_recipient_bounce,
        check_policy_service inet:127.0.0.1:10045,
        permit
-----------------------
and the cache just took a while to populate counters...

Comment: Great! Glad you got it going!

Answer (score 1):

You should not use "smtpd_recipient_restrictions" for a "action=rcpt(...)" as it needs to know the recipient_count attribute. From the man page:

```
 rcpt (<item>/<max>/<time>/<action>) 
   this command works similar to the rate() command with the difference,
   that the rate counter is increased by the request's recipient_count
   attribute. to do this reliably you should call postfwd from 
   smtpd_data_restrictions or smtpd_end_of_data_restrictions. if you want
   to be sure, you could check it within the ruleset:
      # recipient count limit 3 per hour per client
      id=RCPT01 ;  protocol_state==END-OF-MESSAGE ;  client_address!=10.1.1.1
         action=rcpt(client_address/3/3600/450 4.7.1 sorry, max 3 recipients per hour)
```

So, if you use "check_policy_service inet:127.0.0.1:10045" in smtpd_data_restrictions instead, it will work. Hope so.